# Update a row from table view where id='something' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to do something like update a tableCell productCounter = count where productId = 'iphone' from the app.

I was thinking to get all the index paths of the table, then check which cell has productID == 'iPhone' and update that. But I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this in Swift.

Comment: `tableView.visibleCells.map {
            tableView.indexPath(for: $0)
        }`

Comment: @dengApro Why not use `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need to update the visible cells, get the array of visible index paths from the table view. Then look at the corresponding data in your data model to find which ones match. Then tell the table view to reload just those matching index paths.

This is a more efficient solution than your basic idea since there is no need to check the data for rows that are not currently visible.